# Regex to Split any XML Tag on Text Using PHP

Tags: php, xml, regex, text

This is a text sample from my problem:

```
The <tag1>quick brown fox</tag1> <tag2>jumps over</tag2> the lazy <tag1>dog</tag1>
```

Can I do this:

```
array_text[0] => The
array_text[1] => <tag1>quick brown fox</tag1>
array_text[2] => <tag2>jumps over</tag2>
array_text[3] => the
array_text[4] => lazy
array_text[5] => <tag1>dog</tag1>
```

I believe this could be done with regular expression (maybe). But I don't know if there is another better method. Really, I am not good in regular expression.

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: your 3 and 4 didn't have any xml why did that split

Comment: I believe he is splitting by spaces unless within tags

Comment: If it's valid XML, then there's a plethora of extensions to choose from: http://php.net/refs.xml

Comment: Sorry for my uncompleted question. The plain texts were splitted too, so I think the regex is detect the space, "<", and ">" character to split all of them.

Comment: How complex can the XML get? Parsing complex nested XML (or HTML) with regexes is incredibly tricky and error-prone, so in the general case, always use an XML parser. If the string is only ever as complex as the example, however, a regex *might* make sense.

Comment: That example is quite representative for my problems. There is 6 type of tag in the text without parent and child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I just realized, I got an answer from my previous question: [Count Words on XML Text Using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17669369/count-words-on-xml-text-using-php)

I am just add little bit of code so I could got an output like this question, here's the code:

```
$xml_text = 'The <tag1>quick brown fox</tag1> <tag2>jumps over</tag2> the lazy <tag1>dog</tag1>';

$doc    = new DOMDocument();
$result = $doc->loadXML(sprintf('<root>%s</root>', $xml_text));

function utf8_count_words($string) {
    return (int)str_word_count($string);
}

$word_count = 0;
$array_text = array();
$i = 0;
foreach ($doc->documentElement->childNodes as $node) {
    switch ($node->nodeType) {
        case XML_ELEMENT_NODE:
            $array_text[$i] = "<".$node->nodeName.">".$node->nodeValue."</".$node->nodeName.">";
            $i++;
            break;
        case XML_TEXT_NODE:
            $data_split = explode(" ", $node->data);
            for ($j=0; $j<count($data_split) ; $j++) { 
                if ($data_split[$j] != "") {
                    $array_text[$i] = $data_split[$j];
                    $i++;   
                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            throw new Exception(sprintf('Unexpected nodeType in XML-text: %d', $node->nodeType));
    }
}

var_dump($array_text);
```

Thanks for your attention. :D